# How To Construct a dictionary for each line in HTML file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So I am working with this URL (http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/1000.html).

And I am trying to construct a dictionary for each Hebrew word entry.

What I have right now just outputs every file that I am trying to collect. However, I am stuck at how to loop through each word in the website and construct a dictionary for it. Below is my code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

raw_html = open('/Users/gansaikhanshur/TESTING/webScraping/1000.html').read()
# lxml is faster. If you don't have it, pip install lxml
html = BeautifulSoup(raw_html, 'lxml')

# outputs: "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/files/heb-anc-sm-beyt.jpg"
images = html.find_all('img', src=re.compile('.jpg$'))
for image in images:
    image = re.sub(
        r"..\/..\/", r"http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/", image['src'])
    # print(image)

# outputs: "unicode_hebrew_text"
fonts = html.find_all('font', face="arial", size="+1")
for f in fonts:
    f = f.string.strip()
    print(f)

# outputs: "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/audio/998.mp3"
mp3links = html.find_all('a', href=re.compile('.mp3$'))
for mp3 in mp3links:
    mp3 = "http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/" + \
        mp3['href'].replace("\t", '')
    # print(mp3)
```

So in the HTML file we have for example,

```
<!--501-1000--> <A Name=    505 ></A>   <IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-pey.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-lamed.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg">   <Font face="arial" size="+1">  &#1488;&#1462;&#1500;&#1462;&#1507; </Font>     e-leph  <BR>    Thousand    <BR>    Ten times one hundred in amount or number.  <BR>Strong's Number:    505 <BR><A HREF="audio/ 505 .mp3"><IMG SRC="../../files/icon_audio.gif"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#505><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>
    <A Name=    517 ></A>   <IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-mem.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg">   <Font face="arial" size="+1">  &#1488;&#1461;&#1501;   </Font>     eym <BR>    Mother  <BR>    A female parent. Maternal tenderness or affection. One who fulfills the role of a mother.   <BR>Strong's Number:    517 <BR><A HREF="audio/ 517 .mp3"><IMG SRC="../../files/icon_audio.gif"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#517><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>
    <A Name=    518 ></A>   <IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-mem.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-yud.jpg"><IMG SRC="../../files/heb-anc-sm-aleph.jpg">     <Font face="arial" size="+1">  &#1488;&#1460;&#1501;   </Font>     eem <BR>    If  <BR>    Allowing that; on condition that. A desire to bind two ideas together.  <BR>Strong's Number:    518 <BR><A HREF="audio/ 518 .mp3"><IMG SRC="../../files/icon_audio.gif"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></A><BR> <A HREF=../ahlb/aleph.html#518><Font color=A50000><B>AHLB</B></Font></A>    <HR>
```

I would like to loop through each of these but they start at line 100. I would like to make it work for every file that is similar to this so I cannot specify any line number. I downloaded the html using wget.

Or would it be easier to use xpath?

So in the end, I would like to have something like below.

```
{dict_1: [img1, img2, img3], hebrewTxt: hebrewtxt, pronunciation: prununciation, audio_file: audiofile}
{dict_2: [img1, img2, img3, img4], hebrewTxt: hebrewtxt, pronunciation: prununciation, audio_file: audiofile}
{dict3... and so on
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that (almost) each line is a set of img, mp3, font, etc.
hence, I think you can parse the html line by line and extract the information you need on the fly.

For sake of simplicity I've only created the functions to extract the source image link `src` and the media link `mp3`.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

def getsrc(str):
    """ Get a string and returns the link of the src image, if any. None otherwise"""
    if str is not None:
        src = re.search('src="(.*\.jpg)"', str)
        if src is not None:
            return src.group(1)

    return None


def getmp3(str):
    """ Get a string and returns the link of the mp3 media, if any. None otherwise"""
    if str is not None:
        src = re.search('href="(.*\.mp3)"', str)
        if src is not None:
            return src.group(1)

    return None


# ---------------

raw_html = open('./page.html').readlines()

for line in raw_html:
    html = BeautifulSoup(line, 'lxml')

    # Image
    img = str(html.find('img'))
    src = getsrc(img)

    # Mp3 link
    a = str(html.find_all('a'))
    mp3 = getmp3(a)

    dictionary = {
        'src':src,
        'media': mp3
    }

    print(dictionary)
```

The output of this snippet is something like:

```
{'src': './page_files/heb-anc-sm-hey.jpg', 'media': 'http://www.ancient-hebrew.org/m/dictionary/audio/998.mp3'}
```